# Encode video via GPU - slow speed

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, nvenc

My PC: ryzen 5700x, 32 GB RAM 3200 MHz, RTX 4070Ti Super, SSD.
I encode video from h264 to h265 using ffmpeg (nvenc) and GPU.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mov" -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc:v vbr -cq:v 34 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "output.mkv"
```

When my GPU was gtx 1660, speed of encode was approx. 13x.
Right now I have RTX 4070ti Super and speed of encode approx. 16x.
And I'm slightly dissapointed. I mean, I expected bigger speed.
Maybe, I do something wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try using GPU decoding: `ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "input.mov" -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc:v vbr -cq:v 34 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "output.mkv"`

Comment: Hi, thank you. But with -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda speed become something around x2.